# Using Lombok in Codenvy IDE

Tags: maven, lombok, codenvy

I'm trying to develop a Maven Project under the Codenvy classic IDE and I don't want to write getters/setters boilerplate so I had lombok's as dependency to my pom and try to develop my bean under Codenvy.

Although this code building, under oldfashioned Eclipse IDE, is OK and I don't see any compilation issues, I have problems with Codenvy IDE that doesn't seems to bind its compiled dependencies with the build directory.

Does anyone already deal with this problem and found a solution. Any help or even tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems that lombok provides plugin for Eclipse Integration. This plugin add the invokation of a Java AnnotationProcessor when the IDE parse source files in ordre to make dynamics methods available in IDE outline. My bad, this means that unless Codenvy'ld allow the customization of the file parsing process, it won't be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This new plugin will help you to install lambok on Codeenvy (Eclipse che)

https://github.com/KakashiMamun/plugin-lombok